# Dados de uma tabela A não contidos na Tabela B

Tags: php, mysql

Seguintes tabelas:

Tabela: Usuarios

Id , Nome

Tabela: Cartão

Id, IdUsuario, Descricao

Faço a consulta para saber quais usuário não tem cartão:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios as u 
LEFT JOIN cartao as c ON c.IdUsuario != u.Id
```

O resultado não retornar apenas os usuários que não tem cartão, retorna também os que tem cartão.

Gostaria de retornar apenas os usuários sem cartão.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fazendo sem subquery, basta fazer um `WHERE` e retornar todos que tiverem o `idCartao` null. Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM usuario as u 
       LEFT JOIN cartao as c ON (c.IdUsuario = u.Id)//Altere aqui para igual
WHERE c.id is null//retorne todos que não possuem cartão
```

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar um `NOT IN()` para saber quais usuários não tem cartões associados:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT IdUsuario FROM cartao)
```

A consulta pode ser traduzida como, selecione todos os usuarios onde o `id` não exista(ou não tenha correspondência) na tabela de cartao.

Comment: sem usar uma subconsulta, teria como?

Comment: @lelopes eu não conheço, pode ser que exista.

Answer (score 4):

não sei quanto ao MySQL, mas no SQL Server é possível escrever de 3 formas diferentes:

**NOT IN**

```
SELECT usuarios.* 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT IdUsuario 
    FROM cartao
)
```

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT usuarios.* 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE id NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT IdUsuario 
    FROM cartao
)
```

**LEFT JOIN combinado ao IS NULL**

```
SELECT usuarios.* 
FROM usuarios 
LEFT JOIN cartao ON usuarios.id = cartao.IdUsuario 
WHERE cartao.IdUsuario IS NULL
```

novamente, não sei quanto ao MySQL, mas no SQL Server, as alternativas `NOT IN` e `NOT EXISTS` apresentam um melhor desempenho quando comparadas ao `LEFT JOIN`.

Vale lembrar também que este resultado (melhor ou pior) também vai depender da versão do Motor do Banco, o que pode ser lento em uma versão antiga, pode ser rápido em uma versão mais atual.

No link abaixo existe um detalhamento (`SQL Server`) sobre a afirmação que fiz acima (em todo caso você deve fazer os seus próprios testes usando o seu ambiente):

[`NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a forma mais simples é essa:

```
SELECT * 
FROM usuarios as u 
LEFT JOIN cartao as c ON c.IdUsuario = u.Id where IdUsuario is Null
```

Seja feliz :D

Answer (score -2):

Anteriormente eu usava o SQLSERVER ENTERPRISE, porém agora estamos usando o PRO, eu possuía vários script's com subquery's que eram executados sem prob. com boa performance. Depois de mudou p/ PRO, a performance caiu drasticamente. Tive de reescrever alguns script's sem o uso das subquery.
Abaixo está um script p/ quem quiser fazer seu testes ..
CREATE TABLE #TABA (
IDTABA NUMERIC(2)
,DESCRI_TABA CHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE #TABB (
IDTABB NUMERIC(2)
,DESCRI_TABB CHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO #TABA (IDTABA, DESCRI_TABA)
VALUES (1, 'DESCR 01'),
(2, 'DESCR 02'),
(3, 'DESCR 03'),
(4, 'DESCR 04')

INSERT INTO #TABB (IDTABB, DESCRI_TABB)
VALUES (1, 'DESCR 01'),
(2, 'DESCR 02'),
(4, 'DESCR 04'),
(5, 'DESCR 05'),
(6, 'DESCR 06')

---SELECT A x B, A não contido em B

SELECT A.*
FROM #TABA A
WHERE A.IDTABA NOT IN (SELECT B.IDTABB FROM #TABB B)

SELECT A.* , B.*                                                --- mesmo resiultado do select anterior, porém sem subquery
FROM #TABA A
LEFT JOIN #TABB AS B ON (B.IDTABB = A.IDTABA)
WHERE B.IDTABB IS NULL